# MongooseJS - distinct with filter and sort

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a list of locations with addresses, I want to get a list of cities in a state. So a distinct list of cities. by state.

```
Locations.find( {'address.state':state}, {_id:1,'address':1,'name':1}, callback );
```

Gives me a full list, by a specific state.

```
Locations.distinct( 'address.city',{'address.state':state},{$sort:{'address.city':1}}, callback );
```

This also, does not work.

```
Locations.distinct( 'address.city',{'address.state':state} ).sort().exec(callback);
```

This seems to give me a list of cities, but it's not sorted alphabetically...So I'm having a hard time checking my data.

Searching on AL I get,

```
"Atmore",
"Daleville",
"Abbeville",
"Bessemer",
"Alberta",
"Huntsville",
"Addison",
"Albertville",
"Helena",
"Alexandria",
...
```

Help - Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As such the mongdb distinct function returns an array of distinct values so you can't chain any other operation like sort in your case.

As with find it returns cursor you can apply sort to sort the returned data.

For non distinct results with sort you can use

```
Locations.find( {'address.state':state}, {_id:1,'address':1,'name':1}).sort({'address.city':1}).exec(callback);
```

For both distinct and sort you've to use aggregation.

```
Locations.aggregate( [{$match:{'address.state':state}},{$group:{_id:'$address.city'}},{$sort:{_id:1}}).exec(callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to mongoose v5.0.4 documentation of [sort](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort) I quote :

[image]

---

It can be notified that actually it is a mongoose restriction.In mongodb 3.6 documentation of [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/distinct/) and [sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) there is no reference to it.